# How to write full output to a file in python without appending

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm calling the cFile(string) right after the `for` loop which will return couple of strings. When I use `'a+'` it is logging all the string data(20lines) to the existing file, but when I use `'w+'` it is only writing 1line (first loop output). So, to test I have added print statement and I see it is printing all 20lines in both cases.

```
def cFile(input_file):
    f = open(r'c:\logs\temp\file.log','a+') \\20lines output but appending.
    f.write(input_file)
    f.close();

def cFile(input_file):
    f = open(r'c:\logs\temp\file.log','w+') \\1 line output
    f.write(input_file)
    f.close();
```

Is there a way I can clean the log file before writing all the data using `a+` ?
OR is it possible to write whole output to the file using `w+` ? I only want the output of that run in the file.

**For loop**

```
 for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(p):
    my_paths.append(filenames)
    for filename in filenames:
            string_output='hello'
#print (string_output);
cFile(string_output)
```

Comment: What does the for loop look like? Seeing that would help.

Comment: @JonahBishop added a sample.

Comment: @Prime, please tell more like **20 lines** means what? Those are paths or just file names? Your final goal is to have all 20  file names in **file.log** using `w+`,  correct✅?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your application, but I don't think re-opening your file everytime is a very good implementation. Consider having a global logger, in your setup phase clear out the file, and set up your logger using the a+ flag.